# How to make an image from a string?

Tags: python, image

I've made some code that makes a cool 2D pattern of dashes from a starting pattern of a's and b's. Now I'm saving it to a string and printing it to the console, but that has a limited size of 32x32, also I want to be able to save my creations.

I've looked into saving the pattern as a .jpg using pillow but I didn't understand how to use it.

```
import time

size = 32
x_size = size                  # X Size
y_size = size                  # Y size
a_symbol = "／"
b_symbol = "＼"
to_print = ""
start_time = time.time()
pattern = "abbabaabbaababba"   # Pattern


def getsymbol(index, flip=False):
    to_return = ""
    while index >= len(pattern):
        index = index - len(pattern)
    if index < len(pattern):
        if pattern[index] == "a" and not flip or pattern[index] == "b" and flip:
            to_return += a_symbol
        elif pattern[index] == "b" and not flip or pattern[index] == "a" and flip:
            to_return += b_symbol
    return to_return


def shouldiflip(y):
    while y >= len(pattern):
        y = y - len(pattern)
        if pattern[y] == pattern[0]:
            return False
        else:
            return True


y = 0
while y < y_size:
    x = 0
    while x < x_size:
        if shouldiflip(y):
            to_print += getsymbol(x, True)
        else:
            to_print += getsymbol(x)
        x += 1

    to_print += "\n"
    y += 1

print(to_print)
print("--- %s Seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Did you read the Pillow documentation on how to work with text and image files? It comes with lots of examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a blank image and then add text on top of it.

You can use this code to create the blank image of 32x32

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
 
img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 30), color = (0, 0, 0))
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
```

And then you do a while for each line of your pattern and add it to the image
for line in lines

```
d.text((positionX,positionY), line, fill=(255,255,255))
img.save('my_image.png')
```

The only little problem is that you need to calculate the position where to write the text. You also need to find a monospaced font.